# Ignoring registry key removal

Tags: wix

I have `RegistryKey` marked as `ForceDeleteOnUninstall="yes"`. The package were created while ago. Now I need to produce an upgrade package and during uninstall that `RegistryKey` is being uninstalled BUT I need it to remain. In the newer package I marked `ForceDeleteOnUninstall="no"` but it does not help. Is there any way to override that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the RegistrySearch utility from WiX to read existing key value into variable at the beginning of the installation.

Key will be remove by the uninstallation during upgrade. The installation part will use the property to set the new key value.

Comment: He will also need to schedule RemoveExistingProducts before WriteRegistryValues otherwise the value will still get deleted.